# Uploading an Image file to a Sharepoint List Item of Type Hyperlink or Picture

Tags: image-display, image-upload

I have a custom webpart and I want to upload an image, such that user provides the local path of the image and the image has to be stored in Sharepoint list Item of Type Hyperlink or Picture. The same has to be displayed once upload is complete. The functionality should be provided on the webpart.

How do I go about this, do I start with file upload control and save the image and than use image control to display the image? Can anyone provide me proper guidance as to how to go about the task.

I worked with normal asp application to store image onto the server, by specifying the folder name. [Image Upload](http://howtouseasp.net/how-to-display-image-in-image-control-after-upload-on-the-server-asp-net-c/) This works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uploaded image to a document library and stored the link to the image in the Field of type Hyperlink or Picture.